# Possible values of $|f(1/2)|$ for a non constant holomorphic function f on unit disc with $f(1/3)=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in C :|z| \lt 1\}$ be the open unit disc in $C$ and let $f:D \rightarrow D $ be a non-constant holomorphic function . Suppose that $f(1/3)=0$ . Which of the following are possible values of $|f(1/2)|$ ?

1) 4/5

2) 3/5

3) 2/5

4) 1/5.

I tried constructing $g:D\rightarrow D $ such that $g(0)=0$ so that Schwarz Lemma could be applied .

For eg  $g(z)=f\{(3/4)(z+1/3)\}$ but the problem is that either the zero is not maintained or the domain is affected . The answer is option  4. Please help.

Comment: You may try to precompose with an automorphism $\phi$ of unit disk that maps $0$ to $1/3$, then consider Schwarz lemma for $f \circ \phi$ ..

Answer (score 1):

Using hints from the comment ,I am posting an answer for future viewers.

Let $\psi(z)=\frac{1-3z}{3-z}, z\in D$. Then $\psi(z)$ is an automorphism on $D$ sending 0 to 1/3 and vice-versa.

Let $g(z)=f(\psi(z))$ then $g(0)=0$  and g is holomorphic, so by Schwarz Lemma $|g(z)|\le |z|,z\in D$. Now $\psi (-1/5)=1/2 $ gives $|g(-1/5)|=|f(1/2)|\le 1/5$. So answer is option 4.